# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at.. "

Tags: javascript, css

I practiced the styling as shown below in a different document and it worked there for paragraphs and buttons but, for divs, however, it refuses to do so.

The first `document.getElementById('red').style.width="100px";` statement returns an error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at.. "

When I tried it in another document, it worked without placing the styles inside a `function myFunction() {}` statment

Any ideas?

```
<div class="red" > some content</div>
<div class="blue" > some content</div>
<div class="green" > some content</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById('red').style.width="100px";
document.getElementById('blue').style.width="100px";
document.getElementById('green').style.width="100px";
document.getElementById('red').style.height="100px";
document.getElementById('blue').style.height="100px";
document.getElementById('green').style.height="100px";
document.getElementById('red').style.backgroundColor="red";
document.getElementById('blue').style.backgroundColor="blue";
document.getElementById('green').style.backgroundColor="green";
document.getElementById('red').style.borderRadius="50px";
document.getElementById('blue').style.borderRadius="50px";
document.getElementById('green').style.borderRadius="50px";

document.getElementById('red').onclick.display="none";
document.getElementById('blue').onclick.display="none";
document.getElementById('green').onclick.display="none";

</script>
```

Comment: You try to `getElementById` but your elements have only class not id

Answer (score 3):

`Cannot read property 'style' of null` this gives you great hint - `of null`. It does mean, it doesn't find element you are looking for.

It's simply because in html you are using classes `<div class="red">`

and ids in javascript `document.getElementById('red')`

Stick to classes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('red')[0]
```

or convert to id

```
<div id="red">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add id to your div's

```
<div class="red" id="red" > some content</div>

document.getElementById('red').style.width="100px";
```

Answer (score 1):

Change (or add) "class='xxx'" to "id='xxx'", then you will be able to get the elements by the corresponding IDs. Otherwise you can try and use https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Answer (score 0):

Select landing page element.

```
let landingPage = document.querySelector("landing-page");
```

Get Array Img.

```
let imgsArray = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"]
```

Change Background Img Url.

```
landingPage.style.backgroundImage = 'imgs./imgaes/"2.jpg"'
```