# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLDivElement.eval

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Im aware there are similar questions to this, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037924/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-style-of-null-at) but they are not solving my problem

In my angular app Im trying to do something on mouseenter so I have set this code up..

**component.ts**
    menu: AppMenu = null;

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.menu = this._appNavigationService.getMenu();
    const menu = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#m_ver_menu');
    const subheading = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#sub-menu');
    menu.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        subheading.style.height = '100%';
    });
}
```

**component.html**

```
<div id="sub-menu" *ngIf="menuItem.items.length">...</div>
```

**component.scss**

```
#sub-menu{
   height: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

but for some reason when I `mouseenter` `menu` I keep getting this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLDivElement.eval` so its found the `#menu` element so im not sure why it cant find the other element that I have selected.. I think that it must be because the `*ngIf` hasnt been triggered by the time it tries to find the element is there a way to wait for the *ngIf to come through and then 'get' the element I have tried to do this..

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.menu = this._appNavigationService.getMenu();
    // hover effects
    const menu = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#m_ver_menu');
    if (this.menu.items.length) {
        const subheading = <HTMLElement>document.querySelector('#sub-menu');
        menu.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            subheading.style.height = '100%';
        });
    }
}
```

but that isnt working either, Im getting the same error

Is there something Im missing??

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: why aren't you doing this with angular patterns - ids must be unique. i'm guessing the element isn't in the dom by the time the init is called.

Comment: @DanielA.White hey yeah sorry I just edited the question with more information

Comment: Like @DanielA.White said, this is not the Angular way to do things but if you want to use that technique, try with `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Comment: Im not sure what angular patterns are @DanielA.White care to explain how I could do this differently?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I got it working with `ngAfterViewInit` thanks

Comment: Can we see more of the template? There should be an element with the id `m_ver_menu`. There may be a way to get things done with data binding and, if necessary, template reference variables (instead of `addEventListener` and `document.queySelector`).

Comment: you should use the event bindings, not directly manipulate the DOM

Comment: For more details, read [this Angular documentation page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax).